# How to remove some menu item from context menu for Ckeditor4?

Tags: ckeditor4.x

since the "Paste" is not work in browser, I would like to remove it from context menu, and keep other menu items, in CKeditor 4.73.

please advice, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an api method on the editor instance for removing menu items. You can accomplish this by doing the following:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (e) {
    if (e.editor.contextMenu) {
        e.editor.removeMenuItem('paste');
    }
});
```

Comment: when I try this nothing happens?  If I run it in the console I get 'undefined'